# Trigger a click only when certain characters are present in a paragraph with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an accordion with some text marked as "Important". I want the page to automatically open the ones marked "Important" by clicking the button toggle on page load.

I've gotten as far as searching the word "Important" within the title using `$(".diff__filename:contains('sections/')"))` but I don't know how to tell it to click the button next to it.

I chose to use JQuery to avoid having to loop through the class names.

```html
<p class="title">
  Important: Content 1
  <button class="toggle">Open</button>
</p>
<p class="title">
  Content 2
  <button class="toggle">Open</button>
</p>
<p class="title">
  Content 3
  <button class="toggle">Open</button>
</p>
<p class="title">
  Important: Content 4
  <button class="toggle">Open</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Should be able to achieve this by using $(".diff__filename:contains('sections/')")).find('button').click()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `:contains` on an element, then trigger a click:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {
    let name = $(this).data('name');
    console.log('click on:', name);
  });

  $('div p:contains("Important")').find('button').trigger('click');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p class="title">
  Important: Content 1
  <button class="toggle" data-name="Button 1">Open</button>
</p>
<p class="title">
  Content 2
  <button class="toggle" data-name="Button 2">Open</button>
</p>
<p class="title">
  Content 3
  <button class="toggle" data-name="Button 3">Open</button>
</p>
<p class="title">
  Important: Content 4
  <button class="toggle" data-name="Button 4">Open</button>
</p>
</div>
```

Output on load:

```
click on: Button 1
click on: Button 4
```